# I want to compare two date fields, "offer start date" < "offer end date" in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I want to create validation in list for offer start and end date, there are two fields, offer start date and offer end date.
Now start date should not be greater than end date, if this is the case want error message and form should not be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to List settings->Validation settings, then set it like:
[image]

Result is:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is working but user message is not displayed. It shows "There was problem saving your changes. The data source may be invalid."

Comment: you need to make sure you put your user message in "User Message" section. If it still doesn't show error message, you can edit and provide a screenshot in your original to show how you set the validation settings.